# UITextView not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need my UITextView scroll with the text no matter the text size. I can't seem to figure out why my UITextView is scrolling with the size of my text. I gave it abnormal amount of height and everything. Could someone please help me?

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

    self.title = @"About";


    self.scrollView = [[UITextView alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.scrollView);
    //self.aboutLabel.text = [DBConnector returnAboutDescription];

  //  self.aboutLabel.numberOfLines = 0;


    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    //[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
    self.scrollView.text = [DBConnector returnAboutDescription];

    self.scrollView.editable = NO;


  [self.scrollView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(self.scrollView.text.length - 1, 0)];


    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize self.scrollView

Comment: Please check the revision. I dropped it in from the storyboard.

Comment: Ok, where are you calling this code from? Can you post the entire method?

Comment: In viewDidLoad. Check out my update. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an UILabel as a subview.